# Is there a way to add delay to trigger a lambda from S3 upload?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function which is triggered after put/post event of S3 bucket. This works fine if there is only one file uploaded to S3 bucket.

However, at times there could be multiple files uploaded which can take upto 7 minutes to complete the upload process. This triggers my lambda function multiple times which adds overhead of handling this from the code.

Is there any way to either trigger the lambda only once for the complete upload or add delay in the function and avoid multiple execution of Lambda function?

There is no specific interval when the files will be uploaded to S3 hence could not use scheduler.

Comment: Have a play with the Events that trigger the Lambda function. It might be that "All object create events" triggers on parts of a multi-part upload. You might need to choose a combination of other options instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delay feature was added for Lambda that has [Kinesis or DynamoDB Event Sources](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/about-aws/whats-new/2019/09/aws-lambda-now-supports-custom-batch-window-for-kinesis-and-dynamodb-event-sources/) recently. But it's not supported for S3 events.
**You can send events from S3 to SQS. Then your Lambda will consume SQS events. [It consumes them in batch by default](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html).**

Comment: Would it still solve the problem as S3 will continue to send the event to SQS for each file upload which will in turn trigger the lambda function? 

File 1 upload to S3 -> SQS queue with delay of 5 mins -> Trigger lambda function

Comment: Yes. As I wrote Lambda handles SQS events in a batch. Batch size is configurable. That means you can handle 100 files uploaded in a single Lambda invocation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Multi Part Upload is being used here from the client.

Maybe a duplicate of this? - [AWS Lambda and Multipart Upload to/from S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987732/aws-lambda-and-multipart-upload-to-from-s3)

Comment: Is multi-part upload recommended for files less than 100 MB? Because in this case all the files will not exceed 100MB.

Comment: Multi part upload is an upload of a single file by pieces.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative might be to have your Lambda function check for existence of all required files before moving on to the action you need to take.  The Lambda function would still fire each time, but would exit quickly if not all files have been received yet.